# How to use REGEX to print :|: pattern after each string within delimeters

Tags: java, regex

Suppose i have a string `"[cat]:|:[]:|:[dog]:|:[cow]:|:[]:|:[]:|:[monkey]"` like this.
I am able to print `[cat][dog][cow][monkey]` from the above string.
How can i print something like this = `[cat]:|:[dog]:|:[cow]:|:[monkey]`.
please help.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class RegexMain {

        static final String PATTERN = "\\[([^]]+)\\]|\"[^\"]*\"";
        static final Pattern CONTENT = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String test1 = "[cat] [] [dog] [cow] []  [] [monkey]";
            Matcher match = CONTENT.matcher(test1);
            while(match.find()) {
                if(match.group(1).length() != 0) {
                System.out.print(  match.group().trim());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The String `test1` and the one you have *used for explanation* are different

Comment: Welcome to the site. Does you question boils down to "how to remove a specific substring from a string"? It may be more effective when searched.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually not sure what your string is exactly (you are using different ones in your explanation and code). Anyways you can try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "[cat]:|:[]:|:[dog]:|:[cow]:|:[]:|:[]:|:[monkey]";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(":\\[\\]:\\|", ""));
}
```

O/P :

```
[cat]:|:[dog]:|:[cow]:|:[monkey]
```

Comment: actually i want to use "[cat]:|:[]:|:[dog]:|:[cow]:|:[]:|:[]:|:[monkey]" this string as input and get the output [cat]:|:[dog]:|:[cow]:|:[monkey] like this.

Comment: @user3697103: Isn't this solution already doing this for you?

Comment: thanks a lot, @anubhava, its working just fine for me. i really appreciate ur effort.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
System.out.print(  match.group().trim() + ":|:");
```